# How to access the "Deleted Photos" Album on an XR running iOS 13.3?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, album

I would like to delete the photos in my "Deleted Photos" album right now. I have found several websites advising how to do this, but they all say to open Photos and then to click on the Albums tab, and my problem is that when I click on Photos I don't get an Albums tab! When I open up Photos, I can see thumbnails and then at the bottom of the screen there is an icon that enables things to be done to a selected photo (greyed out because no photo is selected), the words "Select Items", and on the right there is the bin icon. There is no "Albums" tab.

I am able to see the names of some albums by selecting a photo and then clicking on "Add to Album", because that gives me a list of albums in which I can save the photo, but the list doesn't include the "Deleted Photos" album.

How do I get to this Album tab that people talk about? And if it no longer exists in iOS 13.3, how else can I delete the "Deleted Photos" album?

Note: I do not use the iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Flip the phone so that it's in the vertical orientation. The tabs will appear at the bottom.

Comment: I had it in that orientation. The strange thing is, the tabs have appeared now. I wonder why they weren't there before. I'll leave this question up because it was a real issue even if it has gone away, and it might recur.

Comment: @ruffle Maybe you've met a bug in the Photos application. Anyway, hiding the tabs is a bad UX practice IMHO.